# How to write this code in a shorter way with apply or purrr:map?

Tags: r, purrr

I am looking for a solution to write my code (below) in a shorter way (It works like this).

I have created a function called calculs_geo () and I am using it with different arguments.

Maybe with an apply() or purrr::map() ?

Many thanks in advance !

```
calculs_geo(maille = "France",filiere = "ensemble", champ = "ensemble")
calculs_geo(maille = "FrancedeProvince",filiere = "ensemble", champ = "ensemble")
calculs_geo(maille = "REG",filiere = "ensemble", champ = "ensemble")
calculs_geo(maille = "DEP",filiere = "ensemble", champ = "ensemble")
calculs_geo(maille = "ZE2020",filiere = "ensemble", champ = "ensemble")

calculs_geo(maille = "France",filiere="logistique", champ = "ensemble")
calculs_geo(maille = "FrancedeProvince",filiere="logistique", champ = "ensemble")
calculs_geo(maille = "REG",filiere="logistique", champ = "ensemble")
calculs_geo(maille = "DEP",filiere="logistique", champ = "ensemble")
calculs_geo(maille = "ZE2020",filiere="logistique", champ = "ensemble")

calculs_geo(maille = "France",filiere="logistique",champ="6_domaines")
calculs_geo(maille = "FrancedeProvince",filiere="logistique",champ="6_domaines")
calculs_geo(maille = "REG",filiere="logistique",champ="6_domaines")
calculs_geo(maille = "DEP",filiere="logistique",champ="6_domaines")
calculs_geo(maille = "ZE2020",filiere="logistique",champ="6_domaines")
```

Comment: We need more information about your data: https://www.tidyverse.org/help/ , it wouldn't hurt to know more about the calculus_geo function as well, to advise on an appropriate output. At a glance it looks like map_2 is the function you'll need, but hard to say without additional information.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't do a reprex because my code works like this and ultimately it doesn't matter what the function contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create 3 vectors of variable names and use `purrr::pmap`

```
mailles<-rep(c("France", "FrancedeProvince", "REG", "DEP", "ZE2020"), times = 3)
filieres<-rep(c("ensemble", "logistique", 'logistique'), each = 5)
champs<-rep(c('ensemble', 'ensemble', "6_domaines"), each = 5)

purrr::pmap(list(mailles, filieres, champs), function(x,y,z) caluculs_geo(x, y, z))
```

This may be simplified into `purrr::pmap(list(mailles, filieres, champs), caluculus_geo)`, hard to tell without seeing the definition of `calculus_geo`

**Illustrative example:**

```
calculs_geo<-function(x, y, z) paste(x, y, z, sep = ' + ')

purrr::pmap(list(mailles, filieres, champs), calculs_geo)

[[1]]
[1] "France + ensemble + ensemble"

[[2]]
[1] "FrancedeProvince + ensemble + ensemble"

[[3]]
[1] "REG + ensemble + ensemble"

[[4]]
[1] "DEP + ensemble + ensemble"

[[5]]
[1] "ZE2020 + ensemble + ensemble"

[[6]]
[1] "France + logistique + ensemble"

[[7]]
[1] "FrancedeProvince + logistique + ensemble"

[[8]]
[1] "REG + logistique + ensemble"

[[9]]
[1] "DEP + logistique + ensemble"

[[10]]
[1] "ZE2020 + logistique + ensemble"

[[11]]
[1] "France + logistique + 6_domaines"

[[12]]
[1] "FrancedeProvince + logistique + 6_domaines"

[[13]]
[1] "REG + logistique + 6_domaines"

[[14]]
[1] "DEP + logistique + 6_domaines"

[[15]]
[1] "ZE2020 + logistique + 6_domaines"
```